# javascript not ouputting response from php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, blogger

I got a simple poll system to work with 2 php files. However, it is not working on blogger (prolly because now 1 file is in HTML)

To be more specific, the poll result gets registered in my db. It is just unable to output the response.

heres my code:

```
<div id="poll" style="width:200px;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;">
Do you like this poll?

<div style="text-align:left;width:180px;margin:0 auto;">
<input type="radio" name="poll" id="poll1" checked>Yes, it`s great
<input type="radio" name="poll" id="poll2">Yes...
<input type="radio" name="poll" id="poll3">Not bad...
<input type="radio" name="poll" id="poll4">No!
</div>
<input type="button" value="Vote!" onClick="vote();"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function vote(){
for(var i=1;i<=4;i++){
if(document.getElementById('poll' + i).checked){
//Check which one has been checked
var sendto = 'http://myhostingadd.com/vote.php?vote=' + i;
}
}
// Call the vote.php file
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
else{
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
//Output the response
document.getElementById('poll').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
</script>
```

Comment: For God's sake use jQuery!! ActiveXObject?!!!

Comment: how do I do that? I'm sorry, i got this off a tutorial

Comment: check [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). Goggling "_jQuery tutorials_" will give plenty of good results. jQuery will make your life a lot easier using the selectors and built in functions.

Comment: alright, thanks. figured it somewhere along jQuery.get().  you're saying that if i used jQuery instead, the problem of the output not being displayed will be solved?

Comment: no I'm saying using a JavaScript framework such as (jQuery, prototype, Yui,...etc.) will make your code cross browser compatible. You might run into an issue that only happens on IE, but works fine on Firefox due to the different implementation of the JavaScript engine in each browser (e.g. innerHTML might work on some browsers, but fail on others). jQuery offer lots of powerful _Selectors_ that lets you easily manipulate the DOM instead of _"getElementBy"_. Instead of checking for **_window.XMLHttpRequest_** jQuery has **_$.ajax_** that handles this part automatically.

Comment: btw use [Firebug](http://http://getfirebug.com/) and make sure your AJAX request is sent correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your **sendto** variable is declared locally in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same question as [innerhtml not working on blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064773/innerhtml-not-working-on-blogger) and the reason it's not working is because the target of an XMLHttpRequest has to be on the same domain. Once the code is ported to Blogger, it will break. (Full answer on the other question)