# innerhtml not working on blogger

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml, blogger

I'm working on a simple vote system. It works fine when the two files are together(locally).

However, when I publish it on blogger, it is unable to output the results. (on click the vote gets registered on the webhost, but the results just don't show!)

heres my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getVote(int)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://pacontest.eu.pn/poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like this?</h3>
<form>
Yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)" />
No:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `innerHTML` that's not working. It's your call to an external site. You can't use XMLHttpRequest to get a resource from outside your domain: it's called a *cross-domain restriction* and is built into browser specifications.

It works when the PHP is hosted on the same domain as the code which `GET`s it, because that's not cross-domain.

You can get round the restriction by using a *proxy script* on your domain: the page requests the result from that server-side script and that script gets the result from the true location, returning that result to the browser.

That's not likely to be an option for Blogger, so Blogger provide [their own poll widget](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42077).

Comment: Thanks you so much Andrew! In other words, having my own web hosting service would make this work?